# Abstract Methods/Classes in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, abstract-class

I've realized there's no abstract classes in Objective-C. Is there any way to achieve the same functionality in some other way (a class that can't be instantiated, or methods that MUST be overridden by their subclass)?

Comment: Maybe a protocol would do it, with non-`optional` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly what you want. If you would just use the class as an interface with no implementation then using a protocol instead is best. If you need some base or default implementation then you either document that the class shouldn't be instantiate do directly (common nowadays I think) or you implement the class to throw exceptions if it is instantiated directly (uncommon nowadays). Also throw exceptions in any methods that should be implemented by a subclass and are called on the superclass.

Unless you're creating a framework that will be delivered to other developers it's generally not worth the effort to implement, just document.

Comment: Alright, good answer- if you'd like the cash prize, the bounty is still open in http://www.bountyc.com/bounties/63

Comment: I'm fine with the thanks :)